# Crop an image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I want to crop an image from a specific row onwards. Please help me how can I do this. I am a beginner in Matlab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f9-47085.html

There is a graph editor icon in the screen where you see your graph, it should look like this: [image: Expanded graph editor button]

Press it, you will get a big graph editor, now try pressing on the graph or one of the functions, in the lower right part you can set ranges, this will crop the image.

Answer (score 9):

[This page](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~getreuer/matlabimaging.html) has a lot of great info on dealing with images in matlab.

When you load an image in matlab, it is loaded as a MxNx3 matrix. The third dimension stores the RGB values of each pixel. So to crop an image you simply select just the range of rows and columns you want to keep:

```
cropped_image = image(RowStart:RowEnd,ColStart:ColEnd,:);
```

Comment: it will not work with RGB images, only with grayscale. to deal with RGB you should write `cropped_image=image(RowStart:RowEnd,ColStart:ColEnd,:);`

Answer (score 4):

You can use imcrop function in Matlab
 CropIm = imcrop(I, rectangle);
rectangle  is a four-element position vector [xmin ymin width height] which indicates the size and position of the crop rectangle.

```
Im = imread('test.tif');
Im2 = imcrop(Im,[75 68 130 112]);
imshow(Im), figure, imshow(Im2)
```